# How To Modify Value In Changeset - Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to `phoenix framework`,lets say i  have a model like follow with  changeset

```
schema "users" do
 field :name, :string
 field :email, :string
 field :countryCode, :string
 field :phone, :string
end

def changeset_user_register(struct, params \\%{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name, :email, :countryCode, :phone])
  |> validate_required(:name, [message: "Name Must Not Be Empty"])
  |> validate_required(:countryCode, [message: "countryCode Must Not Be Empty"])
  |> validate_required(:phone, [message: "Phone Number Must Not Be Empty"])
  |> valid_phone_number
end
```

params from form looks like `%{name: 'elixir', countryCode: 'IN', phone: '97989*****'}`

i am currently using [ex_phone_number](https://github.com/socialpaymentsbv/ex_phone_number) to validate phone number, my custom validator `valid_phone_number` looks like follow

```
defp valid_phone_number(struct) do
countryCode = get_field(struct, :countryCode) #get_field used to get values from struct
phone = get_field(struct, :phone)
case ExPhoneNumber.parse(phone, countryCode) do
  {:ok, phone_number} ->
    if ExPhoneNumber.is_valid_number?(phone_number) do
      e156_number = ExPhoneNumber.format(phone_number, :e164)
      %{struct | phone: e156_number}
      struct
    else
      add_error(struct, :phone, "Invalid Phone Number")
    end
  {:error, phone_number}->
    struct
 end
end
```

Instead of storing countryCode and phone in differnt column, I am trying to store `e164` format number to my database so i modify the number `e156_number = ExPhoneNumber.format(phone_number, :e164)`in `changeset` after checking `phone number is valid`.when i trying to update `phone` in struct like follow `%{struct | phone: e156_number}` value is not updating instead it stores value returned from form `%{phone: '97989*****'}`, what mistake i made here and how can i remove countryCode also in changeset?

Comment: Try `put_change(struct, :phone, e156_number)` instead of updating the struct like that.

Comment: @Dogbert eventhough if i use `put_change(struct, :phone, e156_number)` it doesn't reflect,even i tried `force_change` also there is no change

Comment: You need to replace both these lines: `%{struct | phone: e156_number}` and `struct` with that `put_change(...)`. I think you may have only replaced the first line.

Comment: @Dogbert its works, thank u so much. even i delete countryCode using `delete_change`

Comment: So this to be done inside the model class not inside the controller?

Comment: @W.M. correct. I modified inside model class only

Comment: `put_change(struct, :phone, e156_number)` works but it sets the value as /items/new is requested (sets default form's value for the field). I want to change/store the value at create time (only after/as the user hits `submit`). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @W.M.  if u want to change the value first check the value has been set in the changeset or not? once set we can change right

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan, but when it comes to setting the `id` (for example, setting it to current unix timestamp), this cannot be done by Phoenix/Elixir and possibly only by `DB` procedure? correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @W.M.  I am not sure about that, but if you using [mongodb](https://github.com/ankhers/mongodb) instead of mongodb_ecto  we can create by calling `Mongo.object_id` function.  example code [link](https://tomjoro.github.io/2017-02-09-ecto3-mongodb-phoenix/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To modify a value in a changeset, you should to use `Ecto.Changeset.put_change/3`. So, your `if` should look like:

```
if ExPhoneNumber.is_valid_number?(phone_number) do
  e156_number = ExPhoneNumber.format(phone_number, :e164)
  put_change(struct, :phone, e156_number)
else
  add_error(struct, :phone, "Invalid Phone Number")
end
```

Sidenote: `valid_phone_number` here is actually receiving an `Ecto.Changeset`, not the model Struct (technically the `Ecto.Changeset` is also an Elixir Struct but it's not your `User` struct), so `changeset` would be a better name for that variable.